# How to access the JIRA ticket sprint number via python-JIRA

Tags: python, jira

I am querying my JIRA board via the python JIRA module but have been unable to find where in the returned object the sprint number for each ticket is maintained.

E.g. If I am able to return data for all tickets in the board, but have only been able to find information like the ticket summary, status and assignee. Does anyone know how to access during which sprint the ticket was added to the board / moved out of the backlog?

I would like a view of all tickets - completed and currently on the board and during which sprint they were added to the board. The code I am using is

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd

jiraOptions = {'server': "https://######.atlassian.net"}
jira = JIRA(options=jiraOptions, basic_auth=(
    "email", "API key"))

issues = jira.search_issues('project = "Project_Name"')

data = []
for issue in issues:
    summary = issue.fields.summary
    key = issue.key
    status = issue.fields.status.name
    assignee = None
    if hasattr(issue.fields.assignee, 'displayName'):
        assignee = issue.fields.assignee.displayName

    data.append([key, summary, status, assignee, sprint])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['Key', 'Summary', 'Status', 'Assignee'])
```

What do I need to do to also return the sprint data?